# MIPS "Assembly" How to load and store from memory to register with label

Tags: assembly, mips

I'm working on a school work and i just started learning assembly with MIPS.
I have to change this code:

```
   la         $a0, mesg1       
   addiu      $v0, $zero, 4     
   syscall                      
   addiu      $v0, $zero, 5
```

where :

```
    matric: .word 0 
    mesg1:  .asciiz "Enter matriculation number: "
```

and i want to load from the memory the number 2296 to $v0(not to read it from the keyboard) and then store it to the laber matric.
I think that i must change 0 with 2296 like that

```
matric: .word 2296
```

but i cant figure out exactly how to do the rest. Plz help me ..

Comment: It would involve using the `lw` instruction. I suggest that you download _MIPS32™ Architecture For Programmers
Volume II: The MIPS32™ Instruction Set_.

Comment: load a word from memory = `lw [register], [offset]([address register])`, store a word to memory = `sw [register], [offset]([address register])`. By the way, where will the number 2296 come from?

Comment: thank you very much. every one in the school has a number the "Registration Number".. so i have to place my number so the professor knows who i am :)

Comment: i actually did: 
la        $a0, matric
lw        $v0, 0($a0)


and in label matric i placed my number.It runs :)